# Changing the state of a booleon

Tags: python, list

```
class State():

    def __init__(self, state):
        self._state = state

    def change(self): #should not return anything, just changes the state
        self._state = not self._state

class Coin():

    def __init__(self, coin):
        self._coin = []
        for i in range(coin):
            self._coin.append(State(False)._state)

    def __str__(self):
        return "coins:  " + str(self._coin)

    def change_state(self, n):
        self._coin[n] = State(self._coin[n]).change()
```

The problem I'm having with this is that the change_state method changes the state from False/True to None instead of changing it to either True or False. I'm not sure what exactly I did wrong.

```
c1 = Coin(10)
print(c1)
coins:  [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
c1.change_state(4)
print(c1)
coins:  [False, False, False, False, None, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: You aren't actually making use of `State` here; just use booleans in `_coin` and make `change_state` simply `self._coin[n] = not self._coin[n]`

Comment: Why do you have a separate `State` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
self._coin[n] = State(self._coin[n]).change()
```

In Python, if a function or method doesn't specify a return value, it returns `None`.

You should change that line to:

```
self._coin[n] = State(self._coin[n])
self._coin[n].change()
```

rather than using the return value of `change()`.

Comment: Thanks, however is there a way to put True in place instead of <__main__.State object at 0x02757230>? So it looks like this instead: coins:  [False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]

Comment: @Sc4r: Sure, override `__repr__` or `__str__` to print the value of `_state`.